# how to identify all undefined functions in a MATLAB script

Tags: matlab

I have a script developed by previous employee and I need to identify all undefined functions in the script. Currently, I am running the script to find an undefined function and then comment it out to get to the next one. But this is amazingly time-consuming work. Is there any better way?

Comment: Do you mean that you have files that are built as scripts, and not as functions?

Comment: Have you tried any of the reports that Matlab produces, such as the Code Analyzer Report or the Dependency Report ?  I've not used them for what you are trying to do, but they might assist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, I checked, it looks like you want to run the Dependency Report.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks so much!!